# Video Block does not autoplay

Tags: block-editor, videos

When adding a video block to my page and setting the video to `muted` `autoplay` and `playsinline` appears that the block does not contain all attributes and I ended up with a static image.

Does anyone know a fix for this?

Cheers!

[image]

Comment: can you please share your live site link?

Comment: Hi, to help narrow down the cause(s): are you using the newest version of the block editor, available at https://wordpress.org/plugins/gutenberg/? When I published a post with a video according to the blocks settings you describe, my html in the browser was different: `<figure class="wp-block-video"><video autoplay="" controls="" muted="" src="https://plain.test/wp-content/uploads/path-to-my-video.mp4" playsinline=""></video></figure>`